# A React select value get in Flask

Tags: reactjs, forms, flask, select, dropdown

I create a react form and use multiple inputs. I get in flask every input wih request.get_json['name'] but not the input of the select tag.
maybe you can help me. I want to load the studyprogram in mongodb.
Here is my react code:

```
 constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            studyprogram: '',
            password: '',
            confirmpassword:'',
            mai: '',
            ise:'',
            komedia:'',
            otherprogram:''
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()


        const newUser = {
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email,
            studyprogram: this.state.value,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirmpassword: this.state.confirmpassword,
            mai: this.state.mai,
            ise: this.state.ise,
            komedia: this.state.komedia,
            otherprogram: this.state.otherprogram
        }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 left">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="studyprogram">Study program</label>
                <select onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" value={this.state.value}>
                  <option value={this.state.mai} name="mai">Master Angewandte Informatik</option>
                  <option value={this.state.ise} name="ise">Master Computer Engineering</option>
                  <option value={this.state.komedia} name="komedia">Master Angewandte ...</option>
                  <option value={this.state.otherprogram} name="otherprogram">Other</option>
                </select>
...
```

And my flask code:

```
CORS(app)

@app.route('/users/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    users = mongo.db.users
    existing_user = users.find_one({'username':request.get_json()['username']})

    if existing_user is None:
        passwordtest = request.get_json()['password']
        if passwordtest == request.get_json()['confirmpassword']:
            username = request.get_json()['username']
            email = request.get_json()['email']
            password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.get_json()['password']).decode('utf-8')
            created = datetime.utcnow()
            mai = request.get_json['mai']
            ise = request.get_json()['email']
            komedia = request.get_json()['password']
            otherprogram = request.get_json()['confirmpassword']
            studyprogram = ''
            if not mai is None:
                studyprogram = mai
            elif not ise is None:
                studyprogram = ise
            elif not komedia is None:
                studyprogram = komedia
            elif not otherprogram is None:
                studyprogram = otherprogram

            uid = users.insert({
                'username': username,
                'email': email,
                'studyprogram': studyprogram,
                'password': password,
                'created': created
            })
```

Like I said i get every value but not the values of select, then i get the error:
*mai = request.get_json()['mai']
KeyError: 'mai'*

The Problem is I think the get_json() if i comment it out, it works without the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

this function

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

will save to the state `{"" : ""}` since `e.target.name` refers to the name of the select, not the option and `e.target.value` is empty because you initialized it in the state and you never modify it.

I think you are looking for something like this

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({studyprogram: e.target.value})
}

<select onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" value={this.state.studyprogram}>
    <option value="mai">Master Angewandte Informatik</option>
    <option value="ise">Master Computer Engineering</option>
</select>
```

```py
studyprogram = request.get_json()['studyprogram']
```

And then you can delete all your `if elif` in your server since you're going to have the value you need directly